# SQL: Epoch milliseconds timezone issue when using for BETWEEN statement

Tags: sql, kotlin, java-time, epoch, between

What is the correct way to use epoch for storing and querying in database? Currently what we want to do is use the device date time and store its epoch milliseconds in database. However we are getting weird behavior mainly because of timezone issue.

Here are the sample dataset we have

```
amount | dateTime               | epoch
123.00 | 06/26/2023 09:24:39 AM | 1687771479000
456.00 | 06/26/2023 03:51:59 PM | 1687794719000
789.00 | 06/26/2023 04:02:46 PM | 1687795366000
```

We want to perform query where we only get items from **06/26/2023 00:00:00 AM** to **06/26/2023 11:59:59 PM** with this epoch **1687708800000** **1687795199000**. Unfortunately the item with 4PM dateTime is not being include in query result and only show when we move the date to 06/27/2023.

This is how we generate and store the epoch.

```
fun getEpoch(): Long {
    val date = Calendar.getInstance().time
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
    val localDate = LocalDateTime.parse(date.toString(), formatter)
    val timeInMilliseconds = localDate.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli()
  
    return timeInMilliseconds
}
```

Using the above value we will then format it to store a formatted version

```
fun formatEpoch(time: Long): String {
  val dateTimeFormatter = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a")
  dateTimeFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")
  return dateTimeFormatter.format(epoch)
}
```

It seems we have problem dealing with timezone as we can only always get item before 4PM. Any proper way of dealing with timzone? TIA

Comment: 1. To get current UTC timestamp, you can just use `Instant.now()` or `Instant.now().toEpochMilli()`. It will avoid messing with calendar API and datetimeformatter with potentially wrong locales. 2. What database are you storing to ? SQL ? If so, are you using `timestamp` or `timestamp with timezone` data type ?